# On my '99 Grand Am the electric windows, A/C, dash gauges, speedometer stop working sometimes

Tags: ac, power, pontiac, gauges, grand-am

Sometimes they come back on in a few minutes but sometimes it's hours or maybe a day and they will all start working again at same time. Other things like radio, CD player, cruise, horn, wipers, door locks are not affected at all. One mechanic told me it was probably just a fuse or relay. Another said it was the ignition switch and would cost approx. $375 (WOW) Does anyone have any ideas about this? I sure would like it to be the fuse or relay since they said it would be really cheap to fix. Any help appreciated. Kitty

Comment: If you move the ignition key a little while you have the problem, does it start working?

Comment: When you say A/C you mean the compressor stops working or the blower stops working? Or that the HVAC controls don't work? More than likely you're going to need a new ignition switch.